# React native axios network error - certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: ios, laravel, react-native, laravel-valet

Im trying to call my local laravel api via axios from my react native app using http:

```
login: (email, password) => {
          axios
            .post('http://booking-api.valet/login', {
              email: email,
              password: password,
              device_name: 'iphone',
            })
            .then(response => {
              const userResponse = {
                email: response.data.user.email,
                token: response.data.token,
              };
              setUser(userResponse);
              AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userResponse));
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error.response);
              setErrors(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
            });
        },
```

The api is being served on valet and is unsecure

[image]

When i try to make a request to this endpoint via http i get this axios error:

```
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “booking-api.valet” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

After researching i found that i could set this key as true and all would be fine:

[image]

however this is not the case and im still getting the error, even after deleting the ios build folder and re-launching the app

Ive also tried to securing the valet project and using https to make the request but it still wouldnt work

Comment: Your api is using https and the https certificate was not installed correctly, you need to generate the certificate combing `.crt` and `.pem` file or ask the backend team or i.t support to install the ssl certificate correctly and verify it from https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Noman was correct, i figured out that my local laravel valet backend was redirecting me to use https even though i specifically unsecured that project (as seen in the first screenshot of my question)

I tried different ways to stop this from happening such as unlinking the project and linking again (then unsecuring again it again with `valet unsecure *project-name*`) but chrome kept redirecting to https

I the end i was lazy and just created a new laravel project and linked it with valet (it was automatically unsecure using http). This was fine for me as i only currently have a few endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I too had problems with React Native and Laravel Valet working together. My workaround was to use Laravel Artisan's serve command and to point my React Native app to the serve endpoint:

```
php artisan serve
```